# What is the use of @OrderColumn with the Hibernate@LazyCollection annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity(name = "Department")
public static class Department {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "department", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @OrderColumn(name = "order_id")
    @LazyCollection( LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA )
    private List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();

    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity

}
```

So here what is use of @OrderColumn(name = "order_id")?

> So here what is use of @OrderColumn(name = "order_id")?

Answer (score 0):

`@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)` will load single entries of the list on access, instead of the whole collection on first access of any element (as it would for normal JPA lazy loading).

The `@OrderColumn` will store the (0-based) position of the child-entity in the parent-list, so that e.g. the 3rd element of the list can be queried by Hibernate like this:

```
// Hibernate logs:
/* load org.demo.extralazy.ElChild */ select
    elchild0_.id as id1_7_0_,
    elchild0_.my_value as my_value2_7_0_, // <-- just some child attribute
    elchild0_.parent_id as parent_i3_7_0_ 
from
    el_child elchild0_ 
where
    elchild0_.parent_id=123 // <-- just some parent-id
    and elchild0_.el_child_order_column=2 // <-- 0-based element index
```

The size of the collection can then be queried like that:

```
// Hibernate logs: 
select
    max(el_child_order_column) + 1 // <-- (0-based index)
from
    el_child 
where
    parent_id = 123
```

https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-extra-lazy-collections/